# What is the best approach for long running Java code in an XPage?

Tags: xpages

So I have some Java code that takes some time to complete (about 2 minutes). Nothing I can do about that.

But I am wondering how best to approach this in the XPages UI so that the user may still have to wait but has more control/interaction while it is running (not just a spinning wheel).

So from what I can see I can do the following.

- Java class called in XPage wrapped in a thread.
- Java Agent called from XPage in a thread.
- Java Agent called from an XPage, but waits for a document to be updated.
- Eclipse plugin (For in the client) is activated. Not sure how it would talk back to XPage though (via document?).

Any other methods?

If you created the thread in the XPage, is that going to cause any problems at the server end? Will I have to avoid using Notes objects in the Java class?

Comment: Maybe this article by Mark Leusink can give you some inspiration?
http://linqed.eu/?p=174

Comment: Also this one from Niklas Heidloff (OpenNTF) http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=threads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the OSGi Tasklet service, a.k.a. [DOTS](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=OSGI%20Tasklet%20Service%20for%20IBM%20Lotus%20Domino). This approach allows Java tasks to be scheduled or bound to events, just like agents, but perform significantly more efficiently than agents. Perhaps most pertinent to your need is the additional ability to trigger DOTS tasks via the console, which would allow your XPages code to start the Java code merely by issuing a remote console command via the `session` object.

In addition, check out the technique used in the [XSP Starter Kit](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XSP%20Starter%20Kit) to provide a `serverScope` variable. If your code is running in a DOTS task (or even an agent), it's running in a different Java application, so it can't talk directly to the standard scope variables. The `serverScope` approach would theoretically allow you to store objects that can be accessed from both the XPage and the triggered task. This could aid in using Mark's technique, as mentioned above by Per, to convey progress to the user while the task is running: you'd just be storing the progress information in `serverScope` instead of `sessionScope`.

Comment: Thanks. You have given me a lot to read and think on. The serverScope approach looks useful to what I want to do.

Comment: Another approach is to use a thread in XPages: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99U64Q. For XPiNC applications I resort to a classic plug-in and extend the client replicator

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have an agent react on saving new documents in the database instead of kicking of the agent in your application and use threads ( because threads can be very dangerous and could easily kill your http task )

Another thing you could look into is why the code that you want to execute is taking 2 minutes to complete. What is the code for? Doing things in other databases or connect to other non notes resources?

Comment: I echo the second suggestion. The Java runtime is highly optimized within XPages (as opposed to agents), so there's quite a lot you can do in a few milliseconds. If this code is taking 120,000 milliseconds, I feel confident in guaranteeing that it can be significantly optimized. That being said, it's probably unlikely that you can optimize it from 2 minutes to 2 seconds. So once you're sure the code is as efficient as is realistic, see my answer below for an alternative to agents.

Comment: The workflow is 2 minutes (and that is optimized), but I am breaking that up by threading so as to let it run in the background without much interruption.  It's calling out to an old backend server, so the lag is there.